# Conditional assignment of vector in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'd like to assign a vecotr based on a conditional statement.  How do I do this?  This is what I have tried:

```
zero_rows <- ifelse(i == 1, c(2,3,4,7,12),
               ifelse(i == 2, c(4,7,12),
               ifelse(i == 3, c(2,3,4,7,9,12),
               ifelse(i == 4, c(4,7,9),
               ifelse(i == 5, c(4,12),
               ifelse(i == 6, c(9,12),
               ifelse(i == 7, 12,
               ifelse(i == 8, c(2,3,4,7,9,12), 0))))))))
```

and

```
  zero_rows <- case_when(i == 1 ~ c(2,3,4,7,12),
                         i == 2 ~ c(4,7,12),
                         i == 3 ~ c(2,3,4,7,9,12),
                         i == 4 ~ c(4,7,9),
                         i == 5 ~ c(4,12),
                         i == 6 ~ c(9,12),
                         i == 7 ~ 12,
                         i == 8 ~ c(2,3,4,7,9,12),
                         TRUE ~ 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a case for `switch`

```
fn <- function(i) {
   i <- as.character(i)
   switch(i, 
         "1" = c(2,3,4,7,12),
          "2" = c(4,7,12),
          "3" = c(2,3,4,7,9,12),
          "4" = c(4,7,9),
          "5" = c(4,12),                              
          "6" = c(9,12),
          "7" = 12,
          "8" = c(2,3,4,7,9,12), 
         0)


}
```

-testing

```
> fn(1)
[1]  2  3  4  7 12
> fn(2)
[1]  4  7 12
> fn(3)
[1]  2  3  4  7  9 12
> fn(9)
[1] 0
> fn(10)
[1] 0
```

---

If we want to do this on each value of a column ('col1'), use `rowwise` and wrap the output in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(out = list(fn(col1)))
```

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(out = map(col1, fn))
```

---

`ifelse/if_else/case_when` - expects all the arguments to be of same length.  Based on the code showed, it is not the case where the length differ based on the input arguments

Answer (score 2):

It would be most natural to use `i` as an index, like so:

```r
l <- list(c(2, 3, 4, 7, 12),
          c(4, 7, 12),
          c(2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12),
          c(4, 7, 9),
          c(4, 12),
          c(9, 12),
          12,
          c(2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12))

zero_rows <- ifelse(i %in% seq_along(l), l[i], list(0))
```

Though it would be safer and faster to avoid `ifelse` altogether:

```r
ok <- i %in% seq_along(l)
zero_rows <- rep.int(list(0), length(i))
zero_rows[ok] <- l[i[ok]]
```

The first approach assumes that the elements of `i` are all greater than or equal to 1. The second approach supports any numeric `i`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try nested `ifelse` along with `list` like below

```
f <- function(i) {
    ifelse(i == 1, list(c(2, 3, 4, 7, 12)),
        ifelse(i == 2, list(c(4, 7, 12)),
            ifelse(i == 3, list(c(2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12)),
                ifelse(i == 4, list(c(4, 7, 9)),
                    ifelse(i == 5, list(c(4, 12)),
                        ifelse(i == 6, list(c(9, 12)),
                            ifelse(i == 7, list(12),
                                ifelse(i == 8, list(c(2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12)), 0)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )[[1]]
}
```